# How to structure a flask restful api with an angularjs client-side app?

Tags: rest, webserver, angularjs, flask, directory-structure

How can I get both the flask api and the angular app running on the same web-server? Right now I am stuck running the flask-api on one server and the angular app on a separate node web-server (using the angular seed project). This seems less than ideal.

Comment: We are using the same combination at the moment, and just sticking the flask API on a different port.  Interested to see if there is a better solution.  I presume some kind of smart load balancer sitting on port 80 could do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Im currently in the development stages but I am using similar stack. You are right flask needs to be used on a different port, but simply just wrap your api responses around with "(" ")". So that on the angular.js you can accept JSONP and use the flask api responses.